# Is there any way to send multiple objects with files to server

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring

I want to send multiple objects inside one object with images to the server
my object is like this:

```
{ id:1, dep: { id:1, name:"dep1" }, she[{ id:1,name:"she1" }] }
```

Comment: do an array out of it and then send the array

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for help.
I got the solution of my problem.

```
    let data = JSON.stringify([
        { id:1, dep: { id:1, name:"dep1" }, she: [ { id:1, name:"she1" } ] },
        { id:2, dep: { id:2, name:"dep2" }, she: [ { id:2, name:"she2" } ] }
    ]);
    let file = //some image file
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('data', new Blob([data], { type: "application/json"}));
    formData.append('file', file);
    //then send formData with ajax
```

and in controller instead of @ModelAttrivute I use @RequestPart for both data and file in spring boot application. This do the the work I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array whose content will be the "multiple objects"

```
[
    { id:1, dep: { id:1, name:"dep1" }, she: [ { id:1, name:"she1" } ] },
    { id:2, dep: { id:2, name:"dep2" }, she: [ { id:2, name:"she2" } ] }
]
```

then send the array to the server.

Answer (score 0):

For sending multiple objects to the server the efficient way to add your all objects inside an array then you send this array to the server.

```
[obj1, obj2,...]
```